# Assign new instance to other instance

Tags: vb.net, oop, initialization, instance

I'm trying to do something like this in VB.NET:

```
Class Something()

    Sub New()
        Me = OtherThing       'Other instance of the same class 
    End Sub

End Class
```

During object initialization, I want to switch the current instance of the class with previously initialized instance of this class. I need control over the instances that are created.

In my code module, just trying to use it like this:

```
dim thng as Something = new Something
```

I've tried all the variants of `Me`, `MyBase`, `MyClass`. Tried functions that return the right instance and so on.
Don't want to use factory or after init assignment:

```
dim thng as Something = new Something

dim thng = OtherThing
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you passing `OtherThing` into the constuctor? I don't see where it comes from. So like `Sub New(OtherThing as Something)` ?

Comment: If you need to control creation, then I think it's necessary to use private constructors and public shared factory functions that can take care of parceling out the instances.  You can't do anything within a default constructor, because you don't have access to the outside reference.  Trying to re-assign "Me" is pointless because the entire point is to reference the current object, when you have a "Me" you don't have any context for alternatives.

Comment: Give a higher level explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: ['Me' cannot be the target of an assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30062).

Comment: @djv

I have let's say 30 objects of type "Something" with their unique properties and ID's. They are all stored in a collection, so any time I want to use them, I can just return an object existing in that collection and assign it to a new variable. Then I'm sure, that if I change some property in this variable, then I automatically change the already existing object.

In essence, In my code module, whenever I create an object of type Something, it should have new ID or it should be the object that is already stored in collection (editing). So I don't want to recreate existing data.

Comment: What about just `dim thng As Something = OtherThing` (no `New`).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn sure, this is a way to do it. I can of course write code like this in my code module, or use some factory method that would return the proper object, that I want. The whole thing is that I'm just looking for a way to "transform" the object during instantiation into another already existing object. Let's say switch the object during Sub New().

Comment: @PiotrKalinowski You won't be able to do that. The `New` operator allocates a new instance. _That is its entire purpose_, and there's no avoiding it. If you don't want a new instance, don't use `New`. The only thing you _might_ do is have a constructor that takes another instance of the type as an argument. Then you could have code in the constructor to **copy** fields from the argument into the new item... but it's still gonna be a new instance, and you have to write the code to copy the fields yourself.

Comment: .NET is allocating new memory for a new instance when you construct it. How are you planning on unwinding that? You're in a place you shouldn't be.

Comment: What you're asking for makes no sense. Programming objects are modelled on real-world objects. One object can't simply become another. Let's say that that you have a car. You can replace that with another, so your car is now a different object. In programming terms, the reference "you car" has changed its value but the two car objects are still what they were. One car has not become the other. That's an incoherent concept. You can't change the value of `Me`. It refers to the current object and the current object can't become a different object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the constructor public, then you're already in an impossible situation since you actually want to control the process of instantiation. You said `Don't want to use factory`. Sorry, but this is what I think is the best solution for your problem.

```vb
Public Class Something

    Private Shared somethings As New List(Of Something)()
    Private Shared instanceLock As New Object()

    Public Property ID As Integer

    Private Sub New(id As Integer)
        Me.ID = id
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetInstance(id As Integer)
        SyncLock instanceLock
            Dim instance = somethings.SingleOrDefault(Function(s) s.ID = id)
            If instance Is Nothing Then
                instance = New Something(id)
                somethings.Add(instance)
            End If
            Return instance
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Count() As Integer
        Return somethings.Count
    End Function

End Class
```

Use a private constructor and static function to return new and existing instances. Create a new instance or target an existing instance by passing an ID

```vb
Dim something1 = Something.GetInstance(1)
Debug.Print($"Something1.ID = {something1.ID}")
Debug.Print($"Count = {Something.Count}")
Dim something2 = Something.GetInstance(2)
Debug.Print($"Something2.ID = {something2.ID}")
Debug.Print($"Count = {Something.Count}")
Dim someOtherThing = Something.GetInstance(1)
Debug.Print($"SomeOtherThing.ID = {someOtherThing.ID}")
Debug.Print($"Count = {Something.Count}")
```

> Something1.ID = 1
>
> Count = 1
>
> Something2.ID = 2
>
> Count = 2
>
> SomeOtherThing.ID = 1
>
> Count = 2

Answer (score 1):

You can do something slightly different and make the class cloneable.
We can use the function [MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone) which is inherited from `Object` and returns an `Object`. Therefore we must cast the result. Note that the `MemberwiseClone` is protected. So, we cannot call it from outside of the class.

```vb
Public Class Something
    Public Property A As Integer
    Public Property B As String

    Public Function Clone() As Something
        Return DirectCast(MemberwiseClone(), Something)
    End Function
End Class
```

[DirectCast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator) can provide a somewhat better performance than [CType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) when converting from data type Object.

Usage:

```vb
Dim something As New Something()
something.A = 42
something.B = "test"

Dim otherThing As Something = something.Clone()
```

---

Another solution uses a so called copy constructor. It accepts a parameter of the same type, from which it copies the values. This requires some manual work if you have many fields and properties.

```vb
Public Class Something
    ' Default constructor
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    ' Copy constructor
    Public Sub New(other As Something)
        A = other.A
        B = other.B
    End Sub

    Public Property A As Integer
    Public Property B As String
End Class
```

Usage:

```vb
Dim something As New Something()
something.A = 42
something.B = "test"

Dim otherThing As New Something(something)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. They are probably more complex way of just simple assigning newly created object to the already existing one. I was hoping that it could be done during instantiation.

Comment: The `Clone` Function has just one line of code. So, that's not really complex.